# How could one find out using Chrome dev console whether and if so which HTML elements in a complex tree have event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I have a complex HTML page with utility frameworks (like tables). When the mouse pointer is outside of a table, the page neatly scrolls (when the pointer is over a table, it doesn't). Logically some element(s) of the table have event.preventDefault().

So, how by using Chrome debug, it could be found out:

1. Whether any element in a subtree has ev.preventDefault()
2. What exact element(s) have it
3. (probably it can not, but if there's some workaround) Can the the default behavior be enabled from the wrapper HTML element ?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://hackernoon.com/finding-that-pesky-listener-thats-hijacking-your-event-javascript-b590593f2a83), it might be helpful :)